# How to combine MapType columns in a join

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, dictionary, join, pyspark

I'm having two dataframes with the same MapType column. When joining these dataframes I would like to have the key:value pairs of dataframe1 and dataframe2 in the same column, not two seperate ones.

This is for Pyspark 2.0. I'm going to use it on dataframes with each ~200million rows, so a collect or similar approaches will most likely be out of question.

The example dataframes I'm working on right now, both have the schema:

```
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mapCol: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: float (valueContainsNull = true)
```

After joining the dataframes I end up with a schema like this:

```
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mapCol: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: float (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mapCol: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: float (valueContainsNull = true)
```

The goal would be to stay with the original schema (maybe an extra column for dataframe1.ID and dataframe2.ID to accomodate missing rows in one or the other dataframe).

Comment: You'd need `map_concat` that was introduced in 2.4, prior to that need some workarounds such as UDFs

Comment: Thank you, ollik1 :) I guess it will have to be a UDF then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have done your join you can use the `map_concat` (introduced in spark 2.4) function to concatenate two maps into the same map/column

eg:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df_as1 = df.alias("df_as1")
df_as2 = df.alias("df_as2")
joined_df = df_as1.join(df_as2, col("df_as1.name") == col("df_as2.name"), 'inner')
joined_df.select(map_concat("df_as1.map1", "df_as2.map2").alias("map3")).show(truncate=False)
```